# Activate service function on click

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a click function what needs to activate a function and pass some data in, but for now I'm only trying to get the function work in my service but I keep getting 'is not a function' and it drives me a little crazy since I can't figure out why.

My click where I call the services and the function

```
    scope.click = function() {
         infoService.method();
    };
```

The function himself.

```
app.service('infoService', function() {

    function method() {
        return alert('hello world!');
    };

});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
this.method = function(){
   return alert('hello world!');
}
```

Make sure that infoService is injected into your controller also.

Comment: Works perfect! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
app.service('infoService', function() {

    this.method = function () {
        return alert('hello world!');
    };

});
```

The issue here is that you've declared the internal function but its currently only accessible privately (within the service).

Comment: Works perfect! Thanks!

Comment: @Dennis no prob. You should probably accept the other answer since it was first.

Comment: Hahah, I feel bad for you :(

Comment: No need.  Fair is Fair :)  i was late.